# React native component TextInput problem when I write goes crazy

Tags: javascript, react-native, input, components, expo

I created a component called `inputText.js`, which serves to declare a particular input field according to my needs.

I use it inside `login.js`, passing it as Field props of `redux-form`.

The problem that when I begin to write even very slowly begins to start giving me problems, if I start writing faster, I get impatient, the text I write last in the field is mixed with the text already written and is found in the middle, even the stanchette that which indicates where the focus is inside the word is in the middle of the writing.

Link: [Expo](https://snack.expo.io/r1hOHgzZB)

Code: inputText.js

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View } from 'react-native';
import { TextInput, IconButton, Colors } from 'react-native-paper';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialIcons';

const propTypes = {
  mapElement: PropTypes.func,
  onSubmitEditing: PropTypes.func,
  onChangeText: PropTypes.func,
  value: PropTypes.string,
  placeholder: PropTypes.string,
  maxLength: PropTypes.number,
  keyboardType: PropTypes.string,
  secureTextEntry: PropTypes.bool,
  label: PropTypes.string,
};

const defaultProps = {
  mapElement: n => {},
  onSubmitEditing: () => {},
  onChangeText: () => {},
  value: '',
  placeholder: '',
  maxLength: 200,
  keyboardType: 'default',
  secureTextEntry: false,
  label: '',
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  inputBox: {
    width: 300,
    //backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 255,255,0.2)',
    //borderRadius: 25,
    //paddingHorizontal: 16,
    //fontSize: 16,
    //color: '#ffffff',
    //marginVertical: 10,
  },
  icon: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 20,
    right: 10,
  },
});

class InputText extends Component<{}> {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      vPwd: props.secureTextEntry,
    };
  }

  changePwdType = () => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      vPwd: !prevState.vPwd,
    }));
  };

  render() {
    const {
      label,
      placeholder,
      secureTextEntry,
      iconPassword,
      keyboardType,
      maxLength,
      value,
      onChangeText,
      onSubmitEditing,
    } = this.props;
    const { vPwd } = this.state;
    let icEye = vPwd ? 'visibility-off' : 'visibility';

    return (
      <View>
        <TextInput
          style={styles.inputBox}
          placeholder={placeholder}
          secureTextEntry={vPwd}
          keyboardType={keyboardType}
          maxLength={maxLength}
          returnKeyType="next"
          value={value}
          onSubmitEditing={onSubmitEditing}
          onChangeText={onChangeText}
          label={label}
          underlineColor="#fff"
          theme={{
            colors: {
              primary: '#f5a442',
              background: 'transparent',
              placeholder: '#fff',
            },
          }}
        />
        {secureTextEntry && iconPassword && (
          <Icon
            style={styles.icon}
            name={icEye}
            size={25}
            onPress={this.changePwdType}
          />
        )}
      </View>
    );
  }
}

InputText.defaultProps = defaultProps;

InputText.propTypes = propTypes;

export default InputText;
```

Code: login.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, Text, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import { Field, reduxForm } from 'redux-form';
import { HelperText } from 'react-native-paper';

import Logo from '../components/Logo';
import Form from '../components/Form';
import InputText from '../components/InputText';

import { Actions } from 'react-native-router-flux';

class Login extends Component<{}> {
  signup() {
    Actions.signup();
  }

  onSubmit = values => {
    console.log(values);
  };

  renderTextInput = field => {
    const {
      meta: { touched, error },
      label,
      secureTextEntry,
      iconPassword,
      maxLength,
      keyboardType,
      placeholder,
      input: { onChange, ...restInput },
    } = field;
    return (
      <View>
        <InputText
          onChangeText={onChange}
          maxLength={maxLength}
          placeholder={placeholder}
          keyboardType={keyboardType}
          secureTextEntry={secureTextEntry}
          iconPassword={iconPassword}
          label={label}
          {...restInput}
        />
        {touched && error && (
          <HelperText type="error" visible={true}>
            {error}
          </HelperText>
        )}
      </View>
    );
  };

  render() {
    const { handleSubmit } = this.props;
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Logo />
        <View style={styles.inputContainerStyle}>
          <Field
            name="email"
            label="Email"
            placeholder="Email@host.com"
            component={this.renderTextInput}
          />
          <Field
            name="password"
            label="Password"
            placeholder="***********"
            secureTextEntry={true}
            iconPassword={true}
            component={this.renderTextInput}
          />
        </View>
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={styles.button}
          onPress={handleSubmit(this.onSubmit)}>
          <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Login</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <View style={styles.signupTextCont}>
          <Text style={styles.signupText}>Do not have an account yet?</Text>
          <TouchableOpacity>
            <Text style={styles.signupButton}> Signup</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    backgroundColor: '#455a64',
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  signupTextCont: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    alignItems: 'flex-end',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingVertical: 16,
    flexDirection: 'row',
  },
  signupText: {
    color: 'rgba(255,255,255,0.6)',
    fontSize: 16,
  },
  signupButton: {
    color: '#ffffff',
    fontSize: 16,
    fontWeight: '500',
  },
  button: {
    width: 300,
    backgroundColor: '#1c313a',
    borderRadius: 25,
    marginVertical: 10,
    paddingVertical: 13,
  },
  buttonText: {
    fontSize: 16,
    fontWeight: '500',
    color: '#ffffff',
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
  inputContainerStyle: {
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15)',
    padding: 5,
    paddingBottom: 10,
    borderRadius: 5,
  },
});

const validate = values => {
  const errors = {};
  if (!values.email) {
    errors.email = 'Email is required';
  }
  if (!values.password) {
    errors.password = 'Password is required';
  }
  return errors;
};

export default reduxForm({
  form: 'login',
  validate,
})(Login);
```